# Unity game asks permission not reflected in the manifest

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-manifest

So I am developing this game in which some 3rd party SDKs are also included. When I am trying to install the apk, it asks for some permissions, namely:
1- Accessing the contacts,
2- Accessing photos, media and files,
3- Managing phone calls.

However, none of these permissions is mentioned neither in the main Android Manifest.xml file, nor in the 3rd party SDKs' manifests. How is that possible? What should I do to get rid of these permissions?

Answer (score 1):

Your question has too little data to answer your question. What is 3rd party SKDs? I bet your SDKs has permission but you don't know. Just export to android project and check merged android manifest, you can find where the permission required.

Comment: To expand and clarify: some permissions can be detected (such as phone status and file access) due to calls requiring those permissions being present in the code, even without the manifest declaring them.